# Azure MARS Agent still writes to local hard drive

Tags: azure, azure-backup-vault

I originally was using Windows Backup on my Windows 2012R2 servers to back them up to a network drive. Now I am running MARS agent on each to push them up to my Azure Storage account which works fine, but they are still continuing to write to the network drive as well. Is this by design or is there a way for them to only write to the Azure Storage cloud and not the network drive?

Comment: Hi there! Your question is too broad. Here, on stackoverflow, we dealing with coding issues, so if you have a problem with your code (exceptions, unpredictable behavior, etc.) - edit your question or ask another one. You may also find this link useful: [ask]

Comment: Well this is the forum Azure pointed me to. Thanks for the info.